# Switching from JQuery to RightJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, rightjs

I am currently using JQuery and recently heard about [RightJS](http://rightjs.org/). RightJS seems to be faster, lighter & more object oriented. But I was wondering if RightJS has somethings seriously missing compared to JQuery (Other than the huge plugin base).

**Update:** 
I tried RightJS in a small web project & decided to use it on a few more projects. But I would still stick to JQuery till I am confidant about RightJS. So far RightJS seems to be doing all the things I do with JQuery (mostly ajax & selectors).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nahar,

Nikolay, the author of RightJS is here. Couple of notes.

1) Mentioned above jQuery size is incorrect because 24k is the size of the gzipped version. Gzipped RightJS weights 14k.

2) I believe the_drow just don't know what he's talking about. RightJS has all the same as jQuery, Moo, Dojo or Prototype. More of that in RightJS you have things like classes, advanced form-features and cookies already packed into those 14k when jQuery has those things as plugins.

Then RightJS also has custom builds http://rightjs.org/build

As for dojo, I tried it on two projects before, and if you would ask me, I would say spare your time, jQuery is better.

The only problem with RightJS is that it's still an underground and we are still growing the critical mass of users, so occasionally you'll have to use your own brain instead of googling answers.

Comment: You have done an excellent job developing RightJS. I am really loving its OOP & easy hackable design. But as you said it needs to come from underground. may be having an entry in wikipedia js framework comparision.

Comment: I'm working on RightJS 2 at the moment, which will have all sorts of new crazy things, like safe-mode, dom-wrappers, etc. for example http://bit.ly/9e8vom . Once it's out, I'll get back to its promotion. Just don't want to spoil it with RightJS1 for now.

Answer (score 3):

First of all jQuery currently weighs 24KB and rightJS weighs 30KB which means not as lighter as jquery.

Generally, when choosing amongst javascript frameworks, you consider these aspects:

- Selectors
- DOM traversal
- DOM manipulation
- Utility functions
- Event handling
- Ajax

Other than that, one of the most important factors are:

- active/continuous development
- community support

**More Readings:**

http://trends.builtwith.com/javascript

**SideNote:** Thanks for letting me know about RightJS :)

Comment: Thanks for the Tips. Gzipped minified jquery is 24KB, & gzipped minified RightJS is just 14KB. 30KB is the minified RightJS & similar jQuery would be 71KB (JQuery ver 1.4.2 & RightJS ver 1.5.6)

Comment: @nahar: That is good to know but you can concentrate on other things then :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want something faster and more object oriented try [the dojo toolkit](http://www.dojotoolkit.org).
RightJS seems nice but it's like any other minimal toolkit. I believe it's very lacking comparing to the big guns like jQuery, Dojo and Mootools.
With Dojo you can plug a datastore just about to any widget and communicate with the server side easily.
It has all of the quering capabilities jQuery has and also has a custom build process to include only what you need.
It it considered faster then jQuery in certain browsers/use cases but both are great.
There's nothing wrong with jQuery.
Both Dojo and jQuery has great community support and are continually developed.
If you are developing webapps Dojo is the right toolkit for you as it has a very comprehensive UI library.
Just check out their website.
See also this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks).

Comment: There's plenty wrong with jQuery.  From my experience, it's extremely inefficient _(websites need the latest processor, bro!)_, it's fairly buggy _(especially jQuery UI— I honestly don't think they give a shit about drag-and-drop)_, and the API is a mess _(it neither matches JS's native library form nor has consistency within itself; it's just kind of whatever they came up with)_.  **I hope jQuery burns, drowns, suffocates, and dies.**  It's by far the worst thing that's happened to web programming ever _(IMHO)_.